# How would I get number of tiles loaded, and total number loading?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, loading

So new to OpenLayers 3, and I'm trying to create a "loading bar" to indicate how much of a layer has loaded. I'm thinking of making it based on the number of tiles loaded so far divided by the total number of tiles that need to be loaded to render that whole layer from the WMS server-- but I've been looking around the API and I don't know how to get either of those numbers in OpenLayers 3.

Does anyone know anything about this, or alternatively does anyone know a different approach I could use to create a layer loading bar?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this functionality was recently added to the OpenLayers 3 examples.

See [Tile load events](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/tile-load-events.html) for a working example. Note the loading bar right below the map indicating how much it takes to load map tiles.

You can also have a look at the code of the example and notice the use of `tileloadstart`, `tileloadend`, and `tileloaderror` events to handle the loading process.

You can monitor with something like:

```
var tile_loading = 0, tile_loaded = 0;
tileSource.on('tileloadstart', function(){
    ++tile_loading;
});
tileSource.on('tileloadend', function(){
    ++tile_loaded;
    if(tile_loaded == tile_loading){
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but there is no way to monitor when tiles are unloaded so its hard to get a correct view of the number of loaded tiles?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment it is not possible with OpenLayers3. See [this post on the openlayers 3 dev mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ol3-dev/tiles$20loading/ol3-dev/zktMTr2G4X4/uf4b3QBb-kwJ%20https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ol3-dev/tiles$20loading/ol3-dev/_w07WkrclsQ/nbuPvvcAQwkJ)

If you want to get this implemented you can vote for [this issue at github](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2636) project, or maybe start implementing it yourself.

Comment: This trick is worth noting though: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ol3-dev/ScE0A8L6-oc/_107oB8fRu0J